# PHP Exploding date to values and using if statement throwing 500 errors

Tags: php

Here is my code. I know 500 errors are normally an error in coding, but I can't find it. Thanks for your time.

```
$today = "1234";
$appt = "1235";
$date = explode("/", $data[1]); // EXAMPLE DATE IS 06/01/2012
$m = date("m",mktime(0, 0, 0, $date["0"], $date["1"], $date["2"]));
$d = date("d",mktime(0, 0, 0, $date["0"], $date["1"], $date["2"]));
$y = date("Y",mktime(0, 0, 0, $date["0"], $date["1"], $date["2"]));
$appt  = date(mktime(0, 0, 0, "$m", "$d", "$y"));
$today = strtotime("today");

if ($today > $appt) {

} else {
$appt[] = array($data[8],$data[1],$data[2],$data[4],$data[3],$data[7],$data[9],$data[5],$data[15],$data[6],$data[10],$data[12],$data[13],$data[14]);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this code can throw a 500 HTTP error, most of the time it means there's something wrong with your server configuration (httpd.conf, php.ini, .htaccess....)

Comment: But when I remove this portion of the coding, the file works fine.

Comment: I've known certain servers to throw a 500 error if there is an error in the code, as opposed to throwing an error the normal way. Maybe it breaks something nearby?

Comment: Can you look in the server logs what the error message behind the 500 is?

Comment: I think this could be it, I am leaving here in 2 minutes. I'll work on this more tonight and report with a possible solution tomorrow. Thanks for your help thus far. Sorry for asking then running. I didn't expect so many replies so fast, I thought I'd get a couple replies and work on it in the morning. StackOverflow rocks!

Comment: Anybody else read the question title and think it meant that there where 500 errors, and not one "500" error?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I thought :/ A little disappointed, actually.

Comment: So did I, a man should choose the titles wisely. lol

Comment: Why do you use `"$m"` instead of `$m`?

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from your reference of `$date`:

```
$m = date("m",mktime(0, 0, 0, $date["0"], $date["1"], $date["2"]));
$d = date("d",mktime(0, 0, 0, $date["0"], $date["1"], $date["2"]));
$y = date("Y",mktime(0, 0, 0, $date["0"], $date["1"], $date["2"]));
```

You are using `"0"`, `"1"`, and `"2"`. [explode(...)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) returns an int-based array, not string. You should be using

```
$m = date("m",mktime(0, 0, 0, $date[0], $date[1], $date[2]));
$d = date("d",mktime(0, 0, 0, $date[0], $date[1], $date[2]));
$y = date("Y",mktime(0, 0, 0, $date[0], $date[1], $date[2]));
```

A suggestion I want to make is to save what [mktime(...)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) returns to speed up processing time:

```
$mktime = mktime(0, 0, 0, $date[0], $date[1], $date[2]);
$m = date("m", $mktime);
$d = date("d", $mktime);
$y = date("Y", $mktime);
unset($mktime); // http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php
```

---

Unrelated to the original question, but why do you use:

```
$appt  = date(mktime(0, 0, 0, "$m", "$d", "$y"));
```

when you should be using:

```
$appt  = date(mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y));
```

---

Building upon the past two blocks of code, you can use this:

```
$mktime = mktime(0, 0, 0, $date[0], $date[1], $date[2]);
$appt  = date(mktime(
    0, // $hour
    0, // $minute
    0, // $second
    date("m", $mktime), // $month
    date("d", $mktime), // $day
    date("Y", $mktime))); // $year
unset($mktime); // http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php
```

Answer (score -1):

First off all, your code seems a little too overly-complicated.  Try this:

```
$today=strtotime(date("m/d/Y"));
$appt=strtotime($data[1]);
if($today > $appt) {

} else {
    $appt[] = array($data[8],$data[1],$data[2],$data[4],$data[3],$data[7],$data[9],$data[5],$data[15],$data[6],$data[10],$data[12],$data[13],$data[14]);
}
```

Then do some error checking if you are still getting a 500 error:

```
print_r($data);
```

Hopefully that will at least get you in the right direction.